# generating big files using apache camel and freemarker

Tags: apache-camel, out-of-memory, freemarker, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

i'm currently facing a problem of out of memory when i'm trying to generate a big file using freemarker size > 300 MB.(it works well for small files)

```
<to  uri="freemarker:file:{{karaf.home}}/etc/fileGenerator.ftl" />
```

is there a way to avoid this problem ?
my configuration : Apche karaf 4.2.6 : 4GB memory

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:596) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:367) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:94) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:127) ~[?:?]
    at freemarker.core.TextBlock.accept(TextBlock.java:67) ~[?:?]
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:330) ~[?:?]
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:372) ~[?:?]
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executedNestedContentForCollOrSeqListing(IteratorBlock.java:317) ~[?:?]
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedContent(IteratorBlock.java:271) ~[?:?]
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.accept(IteratorBlock.java:242) ~[?:?]
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitIteratorBlock(Environment.java:642) ~[?:?]
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.acceptWithResult(IteratorBlock.java:107) ~[?:?]
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:93) ~[?:?]
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:330) ~[?:?]
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:336) ~[?:?]
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:372) ~[?:?]
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executedNestedContentForCollOrSeqListing(IteratorBlock.java:317) ~[?:?]
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedContent(IteratorBlock.java:271) ~[?:?]
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.accept(IteratorBlock.java:242) ~[?:?]
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitIteratorBlock(Environment.java:642) ~[?:?]
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.acceptWithResult(IteratorBlock.java:107) ~[?:?]
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:93) ~[?:?]
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:330) ~[?:?]
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:372) ~[?:?]
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executedNestedContentForCollOrSeqListing(IteratorBlock.java:317) ~[?:?]
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedContent(IteratorBlock.java:271) ~[?:?]
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.accept(IteratorBlock.java:242) ~[?:?]
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitIteratorBlock(Environment.java:642) ~[?:?]
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.acceptWithResult(IteratorBlock.java:107) ~[?:?]
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:93) ~[?:?]
```

Comment: A typical mistake that people do is passing `StringWriter` to FreeMarker, and then save the resulting `String` into a `File`, instead of directly passing a `FileWriter` to FreeMarker. But I don't know if this is applicable here. Like, what calls FreeMarker?

Comment: Would you please post the exact exception stack trace from the log?

Comment: @MattPavlovich i added the exception to my question

Comment: @ddekany i didn't get your question :(

Comment: @BengagiFoued -- please share the freemarker template as well and what is this Camel route reading from? What version of Camel? Running out of 4GB seems like a FTL template problem, the source reading a really huge piece of data or a bug from a really old version of Camel.

Comment: From the stack trace the problem is what I suspected in my comment. That is, the result is written into a `StringWriter`. I'm not sure if it was Camel that passed such `Writer` to FreeMarker. Please check. It should be a call to `Template.process`, or `Environment.process`, and it should be further down in the stack trace.